# strip html tags except a tag that contain class

Tags: javascript, html, tags, strip

i need regex that strip HTML tags except "a" tag that contain class "classmark"

lets say i have this HTML string:

```
 <b>this</b>
 <a href="#">not match</a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank">not match</a>
 <a href="#" class="classmark" target="_blank">match</a>
 <a href="#" class="classmark">match2</a>
 <a class="classmark" target="_blank">match3</a>
 <a class="classmark">match4</a>
 <b>this</b>
 <p>fggfgf</p>
```

i want the result like this:

```
this
not match
not match
<a href="#" class="classmark" target="_blank">match</a>
<a href="#" class="classmark">match2</a>
<a class="classmark" target="_blank">match3</a>
<a class="classmark">match4</a>
this
fggfgf
```

i use this function to strip HTML tags

```
 function strip_tags( _html /*you can put each single tag per argument*/ )
{   
    var _tags = [], _tag = "" ;

    for( var _a = 1 ; _a < arguments.length ; _a++ )
   {
    _tag = arguments[_a].replace( /<|>/g, '' ).trim() ;
    
    if ( arguments[_a].length > 0 ) _tags.push( _tag, "/"+_tag );
   }

   if ( !( typeof _html == "string" ) && !( _html instanceof String ) ) return "" ;
   else if ( _tags.length == 0 )
   { 
    return _html.replace( /<(\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, "" );

   }
   else
   {  
    var _re = new RegExp( "<(?!("+_tags.join("|")+")\s*\/?)[^>]+>", "g" );
    return _html.replace( _re, '');
   }

 }
```

it will strip HTML tags and keep only the specific tags i want the same function and add with it the class attribute that i need something like this:

```
    strip_tags( HTMLstring , "a" ,"classmark")
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>If I've understood correctly, you can use a regex to test if the html contains a tag `x` with a class attribute `y` and then you can strip the tags with a `.replace(regex, ...)` call. Here's what that could look like:</s>

```
[removed]
```

EDIT:

Ok, misunderstood and thought it was an array of single html tags. So this version first splits them up in to matched html tags (note that this version will not do nested tags), it then maps over all of parts and does the replacing per part. Then joins them back:

```
function strip_tags(_html, _tag, _class) {
  return _html
    // Match each tag and return them as an array of matches
    .match(/<(.+).*?>.*?<\/\1>(.*?)([^<]*)/g) 
    // Map over each tag and check if it is a specific tag with a specific class
    .map(tag => {
      const regex = RegExp(`<${_tag} (.*?)class="${_class}"(.*?)>`);
      // If it is, replace the tag part within nothing, and leave the content
      if (!regex.test(tag)) {
        return tag.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '');
      // If not then just return the tag as is 
      } else {
        return tag;
      }
    })
    // Now join all the mapped tags back together
    .join('');
}
```

EDIT:

If you would like to have a proper HTML parser and go through each element then you can take a look at `DOMParser` and [this link to start with](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

```
let parser = new DOMParser()
let doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html")
doc
  .querySelectorAll('*')
  .forEach(node => {
    console.log(node);
  });
```

Comment: what if string like this:"<a class="mention">test<a href='#' class 'classmark'>@test</a></a>" is will keep only: "test<a href='#' class ='classmark'>@test</a>" ?

Comment: if i test like you function i get result :"test@test" ?

Comment: you function will not work because it test the whole HTML string not one by one

Comment: Right. Edited the answer now.

Comment: check this: '<a>test<a class ="cool">@test</a></a>test'
i need result like this: 'test<a class="cool">@test</a>test'

Comment: No it will not do nested tags. It basically shows the answer to "i want the same function and add with it the class attribute..." So if it's about the class attribute then the regex is up there. If it's about parsing nested html tags in a specific way I think that's too too big a scope for me for now and a different question.